# Detect if Local Notification was fired while app was in background/inactive

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am implementing a local notification feature with the following goal:

> Show this notification if the user has not visited screen X for at least 7 days. **Only display it once**, even if the user does not visit screen X again after the first time the notification has been shown.

My current strategy is to schedule the notification to fire 7 days after the first time the user launches the app. Then, if the user visits screen X before those 7 days, I reschedule that notification which effectively resets the timer to 7 more days. I use a custom class (`NotificationManager`) to manage the setup and scheduling of the notification. You can assume that `NotificationManager`'s implementation is bug-free.

This is my **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // notification was never shown to the user
    if firstEverAppLaunch {
        NotificationManager.shared.schedule(notificationWithIdentifier: "remindUserToVisitScreenX")
    }



func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
         if notification.request.identifier == "remindUserToVisitScreenX" {
             UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "doNotShowNotificationAgain")
         }
}
```

**ScreenXController.swift**

```
//.. some uninteresting code


override func viewWillAppear() {
    // if user notification has never been shown, reschedule (i.e. reset) notification
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "doNotShowNotificationAgain") {
        NotificationManager.shared.schedule(notificationWithIdentifier: "remindUserToVisitScreenX")
    }
{
```

My current implementation works almost correctly by calling `willPresent notification` function. However, if the notification arrives while the app is in the background or inactive, `willPresent` will not get called, and thus the app cannot meet the requirement that the notification be displayed **just once** in the entire lifetime of the app.

*Example:*

User does not visit screen X for a week. The notification triggers while the app is inactive. The user dismisses the notification, and then launches the app, without visiting screen X for another week. At the end of that week, the user receives the notification **again**.

Answer (score 1):

When the user taps or dismisses the notification when the app is in background (suspended) or terminated, the callback will be received in the following `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

If the user taps and opens the app, `response.actionIdentifier` will be "`UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier`".

If the user dismisses by tapping clear option in notification or left-swiping the notification, `response.actionIdentifier` will be "`UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier`".

So, whenever user takes any action in the notification when the app is inactive, it will be  received in this callback. As you expected, 7-day local notification can be scheduled here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Anand, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this won't work because `UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier` does not get called if the user swipes up on the screen (which is what I am looking for). At this point, I wouldn't be surprised if my desired solution is not implementable with the current Apple-provided APIs